# SQLite query isn't working from other PHP file

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have strange issue. When I am running file Database/connectDatabase.php:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:database.db') or die("fail to connect db");
$qry = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name=? AND pass=?");
$qry->execute(array("a", "a")) or die;
```

it's working.
But if I use it in file LoginSystem/registration.php:

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(__ROOT__.'/Database/connectDatabase.php');
```

it's thrownig: "Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in .../Database/connectDatabase.php on line 4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out solution. I was using local path to database ('sqlite:database.db'). PHP probably is pasting code from require - when file with require is in other catalogue code is not working.

Comment: If that solved the problem for you, then you should go ahead and accept your own answer to close the question out.

Comment: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days", but thanks for advice.